# Checkstyle throwsindent property not available

Tags: checkstyle

My checkstyle indentation module does not have "throwsIndent" property. Is there any alternative available for this property?

Checkstyle doc where "throwsIndent" is present - 
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html

Answer (score 1):

The `throwsIndent` property of the [Indentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Indentation) check was added with Checkstyle 5.7, which is the latest version at the time of this writing. As far as I know, there is no workaround for this property for Checkstyle versions prior to 5.7.

So your best bet is to upgrade your Checkstyle version. If you are using Eclipse, you can upgrade to the latest version of the [Eclipse-CS](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) plugin, which will also include the newest Checkstyle. The same is true for [CheckStyle-IDEA](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065), the Checkstyle plugin for IntelliJ IDEA.